# RubyInline: Error: too few arguments to function

Tags: c, ruby, inline

I have the following C code:

```
VALUE find_index(VALUE arr, VALUE num_elements, VALUE element){
  ....
}

....

VALUE array_distance(VALUE arr1, VALUE arr2){
  long arr1_len = RARRAY_LEN(arr1);
  VALUE *c_arr2 = RARRAY_PTR(arr2);
  long i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr2_len; i++){
    long arr1_index = find_index(arr1, arr1_len, c_arr2[i]);
    ....
  }
}
```

When compiling this, I get the following error:

```
In function ‘VALUE array_distance(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:

error: too few arguments to function ‘VALUE find_index(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’
```

Can someone help with what is wrong here?

Comment: ...Name collision? Try a different name from find_index, and see if that works? Only other thing I can think of is that it's inserting an implied `self` in there, which is (one of?) the ways to do OO at lower levels.

Comment: @Narfanator Thanks! The different name did not help. In case it is inserting an implied self, any idea how do we call the function?

Comment: @p11y No.. Not inside `Array` class

Comment: make sure function prototype is correct..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your C functions in other C code inside, you need to use `builder.c_raw` instead of `builder.c`, because RubyInline actually tries to make your life easier by changing your code so you can write simple functions quickly. This is however misleading and keeps you from calling your C functions from inside other C functions, because the method signature is altered. This should get you started:

```
class Test
  inline :C do |builder|
    builder.c_raw <<-'EOC', :arity => 3
      static VALUE
      find_index(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self) {
        VALUE arr = argv[0];
        VALUE num_elements = argv[1];
        VALUE element = argv[2];
        // actual code...
      }
    EOC

    builder.c_raw <<-'EOC', :arity => 2
      static VALUE
      array_distance(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self) {
        long arr1_len = RARRAY_LEN(argv[0]);
        VALUE *c_arr2 = RARRAY_PTR(argv[1]);
        long i;

        for(i = 0; i < arr2_len; i++){
          VALUE[] find_index_argv = {arr1, arr1_len, c_arr2[i]};
          long arr1_index = find_index(argc, find_indev_argv, self);
          // more code...
        }

        // must have a return value!
        return Qnil;
      }
    EOC
  end
end
```

Comment: `VALUE[] find_index_argv = {arr1, arr1_len, c_arr2[i]};` is not working properly. It says `error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token`